# Node Application shows No Gruntfile (grunt.js, Gruntfile.js, Gruntfile.coffee) found

Tags: node.js, angularjs, heroku, gruntjs, mean-stack

After I git push it onto heroku with grunt build pack, it shows the following errors:

```
-----> No Gruntfile (grunt.js, Gruntfile.js, Gruntfile.coffee) found
```

But by checking git, i can sure that there is a gruntfile.js exist and it is successful by running grunt on my local side.

It caused my application cannot be used and have the following result in the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < /build/js/dist.min.js:1
```

Anyway to solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change the filename to `Gruntfile.js` (with a capital G).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by modyfy the content of grunt file and package.json